# Symfony Configuration issues on Mac OS X EL Capitan

Tags: php, symfony

Hi guys i need help to fixed this Symfony configuration issues on my mac. Am using OS X El Capitan:

Am new on Symfony and l get this result after installation.

#### Configuration checker

This script analyzes your system to check whether is ready to run Symfony applications.

#### Major problems

Major problems have been detected and must be fixed before continuing:

app/cache/ or var/cache/ directory must be writable
Change the permissions of either "app/cache/" or "var/cache/" directory so that the web server can write into it.

app/logs/ or var/logs/ directory must be writable
Change the permissions of either "app/logs/" or "var/logs/" directory so that the web server can write into it.

#### Recommendations

Additionally, to enhance your Symfony experience, it’s recommended that you fix the following:

intl ICU version installed on your system (56.1) should match the ICU data bundled with Symfony (55.1)
In most cases you should be fine, but please verify there is no inconsistencies between data provided by Symfony and the intl extension. See https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/15007 for an example of inconsistencies you might run into.

#### a PHP accelerator should be installed

Install and/or enable a PHP accelerator (highly recommended).

Comment: If you want a realistic box, you could look at using docker or vagrant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Kkinsey beat me to it, but here are the official instructions you need to follow for macOS:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html#using-acl-on-a-system-that-supports-chmod-a-macos

It's a permission problem with the var folder (if you are using Symfony3).
The ICU error is really a warning.

If you are using PHP 7.0, then you don't need an accelerator.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Terminal app, go to the Symfony directory, and type:

```
sudo chmod 777 app/logs/
sudo chmod 777 app/cache/
```

You'll be asked for your password.  If you need more information, read [Understanding Unix Permissions](http://www.perlfect.com/articles/chmod.shtml).

As for ICU, I wouldn't worry about it if there are no problems.  As for a PHP accelerator, I'd wait and analyze performance.  ionCube or Zend Optimizer are your likely choices; a quick Google Search indicates they are available...

Comment: i get this response after trying these in terminal chmod: app/cache/: No such file or directory

Comment: What directory are you in when you type this?  Is there an "app" directory there?  If so, then "cache" doesn't exist; start with "mkdir app/cache" and then issue the chmod command.

Comment: BB is my Home directory. under it l have Sites and my symphony project 'hrms_v.1'   i.e. BB/Sites/hrms_v.1